# How to find max or min between a range on an arraylist?

Tags: java

I know there is

```
Collections.max(list);
Collections.min(list);
```

To get the max or min of an arraylist, but I am looking for a way to get the max or min between a certain range.

For example, what is the max between index 0 and index 5?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `list.subList` to run the operation on a portion of the `List`:

```
Collections.max(list.subList(0,6));
```

`list.subList(0,6)` returns a view of the portion of the original list between indices 0 and 5 (inclusive).

Answer (score 7):

You can go with sublist. Make a list with range and then pass it as param to the max.

For ex :

```
Collections.max(list.subList(0,6));
```